# How to prevent escaping sequence when I set Content-Type to application/json?

Tags: python, html, json, jsonp, web.py

My API need to return something with type json,so I set the Content-Type to application/json?

This is my [url](http://southmoneyweixin.sinaapp.com/callback),I don't want the characters to be escaped.

I use webpy framework.

```
def GET(self):
    web.header('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    url = "http://www.reddit.com/r/pics/hot.json"
    hdr = { 'User-Agent' : 'super happy flair bot by /u/spladug' }
    req = urllib2.Request(url, headers=hdr)
    html = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
    gold = json.loads(html)
    return render.callback(gold)
```

This is the sample output:

```
{u&#39;kind&#39;: u&#39;Listing&#39;}
```

I don't want the character escaped.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Seems like Sina App is at fault here to me, but I have no experience with it and the documentation is all in Chinese.

Comment: @frb thx,I add the output in the quesiong,can you have a look?

Answer (score 0):

```
# If ensure_ascii is True (the default), 
# all non-ASCII characters in the output are escaped.
gold = json.loads(html, ensure_ascii=0, sort_keys=1, indent=4)
```